# Node JS File system

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, fs

I'm learning node.js and currently on how to copy file system,

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as fs from 'fs/promises';
fs.copyFileSync("file1.txt", "file2.txt");
```

Using the above in VS code, I get prompts like: remove import from fs for first and second line, the fs in the third line is red, please help

Comment: Try ```import fs from "fs"``` instead of those two imports

Comment: Why _do_ you have two imports trying to target the same name? Only one thing can be called `fs`, which do you want it to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are importing two module as one variable

You can try `import fs from "fs"` and remove the second line, and your code `fs.copyFileSync()` is correct

Comment: Did the job as required. Thanks